# Add additional properties to response

Tags: dart, aqueduct

Using addResponseModifier is it possible to fetch user property and add it to the response body, before the final response?
https://pub.dev/documentation/aqueduct/latest/aqueduct/Request/addResponseModifier.html

```
      .route("/auth/token")
        .linkFunction((req) async {
      req.addResponseModifier((resp) async {
        final q = Query<User>(context)
        ..where((o) => o.username).equalTo(req.body.as()['username'][0] as String);
         final u = await q.fetchOne();
        resp.body = {
          "role": u.role
        };
      });
      return req;
    })
   .link(() => AuthController(authServer));
```

Comment: What is the question here? did you try your code? did it work? does it throw an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that, the method `req.addResponseModifier` is type `vod` and my `async` call for getting the user is executed later on.
Thus, using different endpoint.